# Как сделать сворачивание / разворачивание веток DOM на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, дерево

Сворачивание/разворачивание работает но не пойму как создать этот список автоматически на основе DOM текущего документа, а не вручную

```js
var tree = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var treeLis = tree.getElementsByTagName('li');

/* wrap all textNodes into spans */
for (var i = 0; treeLis.length > i; i++) {
  var li = treeLis[i];

  var span = document.createElement('span');
  li.insertBefore(span, li.firstChild);
  span.appendChild(span.nextSibling);
}

tree.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName != 'SPAN') {
    return;
  }

  var childrenContainer = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  if (!childrenContainer) return; // no children

  childrenContainer.hidden = !childrenContainer.hidden;
}
```

```css
.tree span:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li>HTML
    <ul>
      <li>HEAD</li>
      <li>BODY
        <ul>
          <li>
            div#CONTENT
            <ul>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolloer sit amet</p>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>div#SIDEBAR
            <ul>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolloer sit amet</p>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            div#FOOTER
            <ul>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolloer sit amet</p>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а разве сейчас не на основе DOM?

Comment: Нет <ul class="tree"> это я вручную написал как пример. Нужно чтобы он создавался автоматически в конце документа на основе DOM текущего документа

Comment: в дереве только элементы должны быть? или текстовые узлы тоже? как должно выглядеть дерево. если ты дошел до элемента вроде `<p>text <span>text span</span> text2 </p>`?

Comment: Как в браузере правая кнопка мыши->посмотреть код (нужен только просмотр без редактирования)

Comment: можно с  текстовыми узлами можно и без них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM сам по себе является деревом, поэтому отобразить одно дерево на другое не составляет большого труда, достаточно пройтись по всем узлам и для каждого узла создать элемент `li` с названием узла и, если необходимо, `ul` в котором будут дочерние элементы.

Для обхода можно воспользоваться рекурсивной функцией, например:

```
function generateTree(root) {
  // если детей нет - выходим
  if (root.childNodes.length == 0) return; 

  // создаем список
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  // проходим по всем детям
  return Array.from(root.childNodes).reduce((list, cur) => {
    // для каждого дочернего элемента создаем `li`
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    // выводим заголовок для элемента
    li.innerText = getTitleFromNode(cur);

    // если тип узла - элемент, то идем вглубь
    if (cur.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      var children = generateTree(cur);
      if (children) {
        li.appendChild(children);
      }
    }
    // добавляем созданный `li` в итоговый список
    list.appendChild(li);
    return list;
  }, ul)
}
```

Пример использования:

```js
function generateTree(root) {
  if (root.childNodes.length == 0) return;

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  return Array.from(root.childNodes).reduce((list, cur) => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.innerText = getTitleFromNode(cur);

    if (cur.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      var children = generateTree(cur);
      if (children) {
        li.appendChild(children);
      }
    }
    list.appendChild(li);
    return list;
  }, ul)
}

function createTree(tree) {
  var treeLis = tree.getElementsByTagName('li');

  /* wrap all textNodes into spans */
  for (var i = 0; treeLis.length > i; i++) {
    var li = treeLis[i];

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    li.insertBefore(span, li.firstChild);
    span.appendChild(span.nextSibling);
  }

  tree.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;

    if (target.tagName != 'SPAN') {
      return;
    }

    var childrenContainer = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    if (!childrenContainer) return; // no children

    childrenContainer.hidden = !childrenContainer.hidden;
  }
}

function getTitleFromNode(node) {
  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
      return node.tagName;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
      return node.nodeValue;
    case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
      return `<!--${node.textContent}-->`;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
      return `<!DOCTYPE ${node.name}>`;
    default:
      return node.toString();
  }
}

var t = generateTree(document);
document.body.appendChild(t);
createTree(t);
```

```css
.tree span:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
text
<!-- COMMENT -->
<div>1<span>33</span>2</div>
```

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы подобный список открывался в закрытом (свернутом) виде, а раскрывалась только та ветка, на которую кликаешь?

Comment: @Андрей, можно добавить класс создаваемым спискам или ставить свойство hidden в true