# Как сделать сворачивание / разворачивание веток

Tags: javascript

В теме ["Как сделать сворачивание / разворачивание веток DOM на JavaScript?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/839920/186999) представлен отличный пример раскрывающегося списка.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы подобный список открывался в закрытом (свернутом) виде, а раскрывалась только та ветка, на которую кликаешь?

Comment: Вы об [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839920/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-dom-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript)?

Comment: А нет ли примера вставки свойства hidden в true либо добавления класса создаваемым спискам?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве одного из решений можно передавать дополнительным параметром в функцию, создающую дерево, значение по умолчанию, должно быть оно раскрыто или закрыто.

Для этого можно применить параметры по умолчанию:

```
function generateTree(root, defaultExpanded = true) {
```

далее в коде, просто присвоить это значение:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.hidden = defaultCollapsed;
```

Дальше при первом вызове передаем параметр `false`, чтобы было видно дерево самого верхнего уровня.

```
generateTree(document, false);
```

Так как далее в коде этот метод вызывается без второго параметра, будет использовано значение по умолчанию (true) и все создаваемые поддеревья будут скрыты.

```js
function generateTree(root, defaultCollapsed = true) {
  if (root.childNodes.length == 0) return;

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.hidden = defaultCollapsed;
  return Array.from(root.childNodes).reduce((list, cur) => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.innerText = getTitleFromNode(cur);

    if (cur.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      var children = generateTree(cur);
      if (children) {
        li.appendChild(children);
      }
    }
    list.appendChild(li);
    return list;
  }, ul)
}

function createTree(tree) {
  var treeLis = tree.getElementsByTagName('li');

  /* wrap all textNodes into spans */
  for (var i = 0; treeLis.length > i; i++) {
    var li = treeLis[i];

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    li.insertBefore(span, li.firstChild);
    span.appendChild(span.nextSibling);
  }

  tree.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;

    if (target.tagName != 'SPAN') {
      return;
    }

    var childrenContainer = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    if (!childrenContainer) return; // no children

    childrenContainer.hidden = !childrenContainer.hidden;
  }
}

function getTitleFromNode(node) {
  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
      return node.tagName;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
      return node.nodeValue;
    case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
      return `<!--${node.textContent}-->`;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
      return `<!DOCTYPE ${node.name}>`;
    default:
      return node.toString();
  }
}

var t = generateTree(document, false);
document.body.appendChild(t);
createTree(t);
```

```css
.tree span:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tree span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
text
<!-- COMMENT -->
<div>1<span>33</span>2</div>
```